# Error C2248: 'std::future<Worldlet>::future': can not access private member declared in class std::future<Worldlet>

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I am getting error C2248 when I try to compile this struct:

```
struct LoadingWorldlet {
    int x, z;
    std::future<Worldlet> result;
};
```

I have tried to make result a reference, but then I get error C2512. When I fix that error I then get C2582 in xutility. What is a way to fix this first error without getting the second two, or what is a way to fix both of the second two errors?

Comment: It probably means you are trying to copy an instance of your struct. `future` in not copyable, just move-copyable. Can you post a minimal code example that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `std::future<Worldlet>` with `std::shared_future<Worldlet>` might solve your immediate compiling problem.

But the root of your problem is that probably you want only one consumer of the `std::future`.  You are copying the `struct` somewhere, which is asking for two `future`s to be tied to the same source `promise` (or whatever source).

`std::future` is designed to deliver its data once, to one consumer.  So if you want to move it around, you have to `move` it, not copy it.

As a guess from your error, you are compiling in MSVC2012.  This compiler lacks automatic move constructor and assignment constructor creation.  So try adding an explicit move constructor and move-assign method.

```
struct LoadingWorldlet {
  int x, z;
  std::future<Worldlet> result;
  LoadingWorldlet(LoadingWorldlet&& o):x(o.x),y(o.y),result(std::move(o.result)) {}
  LoadingWorldlet& operator=(LoadingWorldlet&& o) {
    x = o.x;
    y = o.y;
    result = std::move(o.result);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

then, avoid implicitly copying your `LoadingWorldlet`.